# Converting J frame to JApplet

Tags: java, swing, applet, jframe, japplet

I have created a java code (jframe) but i'm trying to convert it to applet so it can appear on a html webpage. Having difficulties converting as I am not too familiar with java coding.

Here is the code so far:

```
 /**
  * Implements a program with a pie chart
 * that shows interactive polling results for three candidates
 */

  import java.awt.*;
  import javax.swing.*;

  public class Poll extends JApplet {

         public void init() {
 public Poll()
   {

 super("Vote for Pat, Ismail, or Clair");
Container c = getContentPane();
c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
PollDisplayPanel chart = new PollDisplayPanel("Pat", "Ismail", "Clair");
PollControlPanel controls = new PollControlPanel(chart);
c.add(chart, BorderLayout.CENTER);
c.add(controls, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

Poll w = new Poll();
}



        }
        }
```

And this is the original Jframe code

```
/**
* Implements a program with a pie chart
* that shows interactive polling results for three candidates
*/

  import java.awt.*;
  import javax.swing.*;

  public class Poll extends JFrame
 {
 public Poll()
  {
    super("Vote for Pat, Ismail, or Clair");

Container c = getContentPane();
c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
PollDisplayPanel chart = new PollDisplayPanel("Pat", "Ismail", "Clair");
PollControlPanel controls = new PollControlPanel(chart);
c.add(chart, BorderLayout.CENTER);
c.add(controls, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  }

   public static void main(String[] args)
  {
Poll w = new Poll();}
   w.setBounds(300, 300, 400, 400);
w.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
w.setVisible(true);
  }
  }
```

Comment: BTW, where is `PollDisplayPanel` and other classes?

Comment: Coding is invented by humans for humans. Along with it comes the responsibility of formatting. We cannot leave this to god since god does not understand code.

Comment: 1) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free). 2) The best way to deploy a Java desktop application is using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: Applets are no longer support and you should stop using them. Instead of trying to convert from a `JFrame` to a `JApplet`, you should move your code so it's based on a `JPanel`, then you can create an instance of it and add it to what ever container you want

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define a method directly inside another. Here you have done the same for the applet. Inside `init()` you are adding constructor `Poll()`.

```
 public void init() {
```

```
    public Poll() {
    super("Vote for Pat, Ismail, or Clair");
```

```
    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    PollDisplayPanel chart = new PollDisplayPanel("Pat", "Ismail", "Clair");
    PollControlPanel controls = new PollControlPanel(chart);
    c.add(chart, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    c.add(controls, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

```
      Poll w = new Poll();
    }
```

```
 }
```

Comment: I think the **Alternate view** is more clear. Please choose between them and edit the answer accordingly. Of course, if you prefer the original version, just [view the edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36927656/revisions) & roll it back.